# r - opencpu - error in executing ocpu_start_app()

Tags: r, opencpu

I found out about opencpu as alternative to Shiny and I started to use it. I am having problem in executing ocpu_start_app(). I manage to get ocpu_start_server() running just fine. I then stopped the server and tried to execute **ocpu_start_app("rwebapps/stocks")** following the manual but I got this error:

```
Error: Application 'rwebapps/stocks' is not installed. Try: opencpu::install_apps('rwebapps/stocks')
```

I tried to install the apps as per instructed **opencpu::install_apps("rwebapps/stocks")** and got another error:

```
Error: Failed to read https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rwebapps/stocks/master/DESCRIPTION. Repsitory does not contain a proper R package.
```

I read around and tried another way to install the app package using **devtools::install_github("rwebapps/stocks")** and got this error:

```
Installation failed: Couldn't resolve host name
```

I thought it is because I don't have internet connection but my internet connection works just fine. In fact I used install.packages("opencpu") to install opencpu package and the 'install.packages' command requires proper internet connection.

Can anybody help?

*My spec/environment below:*

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
Rstudio version:
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.3                         
year           2017                        
month          03                          
day            06                          
svn rev        72310                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
nickname       Another Canoe             
opencpu version:
[1] '2.0.3'
devtools version:
[1] '1.13.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your internet simply is not working, or at least not letting you connect to Github. Can you open [the url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rwebapps/stocks/master/DESCRIPTION) in the browser?

Comment: I can open that url you linked just fine in browser.